# Make two meshes with same topology, vertices, etc identical for UV map transfer

Tags: uv, vertices

I have two meshes, both have the exact same number of vertices/faces/tris and the same topology, but when I transfer the UV maps between them, this happens:

[image]

The same happens when I attempt to transfer the vertex groups and weights between them, the weights are painted in the wrong part of the mesh.

I don't fully understand exactly how meshes work but I assume the problem is the 'order' of the vertices, or something like that.

Is it possible to make the 'order' of the vertices the same as the other mesh so that when transferred the UV map will work?

### The solution

The 'Data Transfer' modifier.

I scaled and positioned the meshes until they were as close as possible to being exactly on top of each other. I applied the 'Data Transfer' modifier and copied the 'Vertex Data' (vertex groups) using the 'Nearest vertex' to the target mesh.

Comment: You probably want to have a look at the *Data transfer* modifier.

Comment: @Jerryno That appears to be exactly what I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: Instead of including the solution in the question box you can answer your question using the answer box below.